# Error: Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.PluginCrashReporter

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

We created a ionic app with angular. When we use

```
 ionic serve
```

Then its working fine. 
But when we are generating android apk then we are getting this error:-

```
 * Where:
 Build file '/home/ankur/projects/ionicdesign/ionic-roots_v101/ionic 
 apps/kisansanchar/medical/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 20

 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.PluginCrashReporter
```

Here is complete log details:-

[Paste Bin](https://pastebin.com/GaBLk8Ca)

Any idea about this error?

Comment: Is gradle installed ?

Comment: Yes, Gradle is installed.

Comment: @pankajagarwal I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.
Digging into gradle command with --scan, I've found the problem.
My ~/.android was owned by root, so my build (launch by my user) failed to read/write into this directory.

Solution: sudo chown -R you:you ~/.android

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the kotlin_version in build.gradle, the one used for building is lower than what was configured for my IDE, so what I did is deleted my .gradle caches by typing this in terminal rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
Then restarted my project in my case it was a flutter project so flutter run is the command. everything is taken care of after that.